# Redirect Varying URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce

I am trying to redirect

```
https://www.fabricdeluxe.com.au/wishlist/*randomly-generated-url
```

to

```
https://www.fabricdeluxe.com.au/my-account/#1526261943144-4a3b22f0-c3d2
```

I have tried the following code in my `.htaccess` however it does not work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wishlist/.*$ http://www.fabricdeluxe.com.au/my-account/#1526261943144-4a3b22f0-c3d2
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

P.S. I have also installed Redirection plugin, so if I can somehow implement the redirect via that plugin, that would be great too!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the Apache rewrite module first, then place your redirections below them:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wishlist^wishlist/.*$ http://www.fabricdeluxe.com.au/my-account/#1526261943144-4a3b22f0-c3d2 [R=301,L, NE]
```

Or as an alternative approach:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wishlist/.*$ http://www.fabricdeluxe.com.au/my-account/#1526261943144-4a3b22f0-c3d2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I have tried to add the code provided, however it still does not work correctly.

Comment: Since the target url contains a fregment You need to use NE  flag to avoid url escaping issues.